# Find out who made changes in VS 2010 with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2010 along with Team Foundation Server.

I know that you can track differences between individual changesets for a file.  Is there a way to find out which team member added a specific code block?

For example, if I highlight a block of code in Visual Studio, is there anyway to find out which changeset was the first to feature that code?

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: For Git users: this is how you "git blame" in TFS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can right-click your SourceControlled file and select [Annotate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx). You'll see who and when last modified each line of the file.

Comment: just noticed, you need some permisions to do this :(

Comment: @Eric: according to msdn only *Read* permission is required (obviously). Does TFS demand something more of you?

Comment: Yes. I'm not the admin and i can't see this option!